# tensor product is only right-exact

Tags: ring-theory

From Page 210 of Introduction to Homological Algebra by Rotman.

Definition: If R is a commutative ring and A is an R-algebra, then an A-module P is extended from R is there is an R-module P$_0$ with P $\cong$ A $\otimes$$_R$ P$_0$.

Example: If V is a free R-module, then A $\otimes$$_R$ V is a free A-module. Similarly, since a projective R-module is a direct summand of a free module, any A-module extended from a projective R-module is itself projective.

My question is: is there something wrong with the projective part since tensor product is only right-exact, so we are not sure if A $\otimes$$_R$ P is still a direct summand of A $\otimes$$_R$ F where F is free.

Another question: if a projective module is extended, must it be extended from a projective? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The tensor product is distributive over direct sums, which is weaker than exactness.

Answer (score 0):

The tensor product does not in general preserve short exact sequences. However, this doesn't mean that *no* short exact sequence is preserved.

For instance, if $0\to X\to Y\to Z\to0$ is a *split* short exact sequence, then $0\to A\otimes_RX\to A\otimes_RY\to A\otimes_RZ\to0$ is exact (and split).

Moreover, the tensor product preserves arbitrary direct sums; since a free $R$-module $F$ is a direct sum of copies of $R$, we obtain that $A\otimes_RF$ is a direct sum of copies of $A\otimes_RR$, so it is a free $A$-module.

Now use the fact that a projective $R$-module is a direct summand of a free module.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing this up! It might be me still being silly. The 2nd question is still not quite clear. in other words, is the 2nd paragraph of your answer if and only if? to answer the 2nd question, we need to go backwards, correct? thx!